# How can I set permissions on a windows share from linux client

Tags: linux, smb

I want to write a script to set permissions on a **windows share** from **linux client**. I know that I can use `smbclient`, `cifs` or `smbfs` to mount windows share from linux. But I have no idea how to set permissions on windows share for a **specific user** from linux. Any help appreciated.

Just for the information, I can set permissions for **windows share** from **windows** with `cacls`. Is there any equivalent command/procedure to set permissions on windows share from linux?

Answer (score 0):

Normally the server (in your case the windows machine) determines what the privileges are.

Short of have the client remotely connect to some program running on the server that has admin rights and that changes the permissions for you or some commandline, you can't.

Answer (score 0):

To grant full read&write access to everyone, you'll need to change the mount command to:

```
sudo mount -t cifs //ipaddress/sharedfoldername /mount/location --verbose -o credentials=/credentials/file/location,file_mode=0666,dir_mode=0777
```

Note that there are no spaces after the commas - that is important here.

Alternatively, you could create a group with `sudo groupadd <groupname>`, add users to it by running `sudo usermod -a -G <groupname> <username>` for each user you wish to add into the group, and then use it in your mount command like this:

```
sudo mount -t cifs //ipaddress/sharedfoldername /mount/location --verbose -o credentials=/credentials/file/location,file_mode=0660,dir_mode=0770,gid=<groupname>
```

You could create a different group for each mount if you wish to manage access separately for each mount. Members of the group will have full access; non-members will have no access at all.